# Error:Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, splistitem

I am retrieving items from SP lists. But when I try to deploy my solution through VS 2013 it says

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or
>   access this resource.

Knowing that I am developing a provider hosted app and retrieving items using CSOM.
Someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure Nedia you follow all the steps explained here: [Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steve_fox/archive/2013/02/18/building-your-first-provider-hosted-app-for-sharepoint-using-windows-azure-part-1.aspx).

Or you can refer this example [here](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/07/deploying-sp2013-provider-hosted.html).

I doubt that there might be some problem with the App permission you are assigning for the app.

Using CSOM you can do your operation but for that first you need to assign the permission to your app to access those functionalities.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I was having this issue and the problem was with the manifest

Answer (score 2):

In `AppManifest.xml` file add Permission for your app.

If you are performing CRUD operations on List Or Library then provide necessary Permission based on scope.

eg: We are using Manage Permission for developer on Site Collection Scope.